# which color format is that?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, colors

**new Color(0.2f, 0.949f, 0.949f, 1);** guys I'm editing an android application in eclipse and I've just encountered with this color code. I've never seen it before. It's obviously not rgb or hex, so can you help me to find the format of it?

Comment: It's sRGB with alpha, but using 0.0 --- 1.0 instead of 0 --- 255

Comment: Go look at the documentation: [`Color(float, float, float, float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(float,%20float,%20float,%20float))

Comment: look at the docu, next  time before asking

Answer (score 2):

Decimal numbers and the `f` suffix are a clue that these are floating-point values. This format for colors is commonly used. Each red, green, blue, and alpha value is in the range from 0.0 to 1.0. You can convert these values to hex by multiplying by 255 decimal (`0xff` hex) and convert the decimal value to hex. See [the `Color` constructor documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)) for details.

Comment: @AlexWien Thanks for the correction. (Also, 0xff is 255, not 256...)

Answer (score 0):

It is Floating Point RGBA representation of Color

```
Color(float red, float green,float blue, float alpha)
```